# Is it just repeat control points and knots if we want to redraw the curve repeatedly

Tags: geometry, curves, spline

Suppose I have a cubic B-spline curve, it has $57$ knots vectors and $53$ control points.  The knot vector is like $(0,0,0,0,1,2,...,50,50,50,50)$
The curve is like this

[image]

If we want to generate the following curve (repeated three times)

[image]

What I think is repeat knot in knot vectors and control points. Of course, I need to delete some internal knot and control points in order to make the number of knots equals number of control points + $4$. But is there any rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cubic basis function are determined by 5 knots each. I.e. your basis functions can be represented as
$(0,0,0,0,1),\ (0,0,0,1,2),\ (0,0,1,2,3)\ .......\ (49,50,50,50,50)$

When translating all basis functions by 50, their representatives change to
$(50,50,50,50,51),\ (50,50,50,51,52),\ (50,50,51,52,53)\ .......\ (99,100,100,100,100)$

Now there is twice as many and you also repeat your control points getting twice as many.

Since $(49,50,50,50,50)$ is followed by $(50,50,50,50,51)$, you should not add any more knots equal to $50$ than those you had already.

Comment: Thanks, Oppenede. The answer is very clear and it works.